# Obtener dimensiones de imagen en directorio PHP

Tags: php, imagen

Intento mostrar una galería de imágenes con sus respectivos atributos de peso y dimensiones de cada archivo de imagen, sin embargo solo me devuelve esos datos en algunos archivos y en otros no, me apoyan en resolver a que se debe?, el var_dump(getimagesize($directory.$archivo)) me da false en el caso de las imágenes que no muestran sus atributos, y en todos los archivos el var_dump($dataFile) si me da la info del archivo, que podría estar mal?

```
        $dirRaiz = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        $directory = $dirRaiz.'/'.$folderImg;
        $dirint = dir($directory);

        // Se comprueba que realmente sea la ruta de un directorio
        if(is_dir($directory)){
            // Recorre todos los elementos del directorio
            while (($archivo = $dirint->read()) !== false) {
                if (preg_match("/jpg/", $archivo) || preg_match("/jpeg/", $archivo) || preg_match("/JPEG/", $archivo) || preg_match("/JPG/", $archivo) || preg_match("/png/", $archivo) || preg_match("/gif/", $archivo) || preg_match("/bmp/", $archivo) || preg_match("/tif/", $archivo || preg_match("/webp/", $archivo))) {
                    // Se muestran todos los archivos y carpetas excepto "." y ".."
                    if(is_file($directory.$archivo) && $directory.$archivo != "." && $directory.$archivo != ".."){
                        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($directory.$archivo);

                        echo '<a class="itemValueInput" data-copy="'.$folderImg.$archivo.'">';
                        echo '<img src="../../../'.$folderImg.$archivo.'" width="100%" heigth="auto" />';
                        echo '<small>Ancho: '.$width.' - Alto: '.$height.'<br />'.filesize($directory.$archivo).' bytes</small></a>';

                        echo '<div><br />var_dump: <pre>'.var_dump(getimagesize($directory.$archivo)).'</pre><br />';
                        $dataFile = pathinfo($directory.$archivo);
                        echo '<br /><pre>pathinfo: '.var_dump($dataFile).'</pre><br /></div>';
                    }
                }
            }
            $dirint->close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que no estás encadenando correctamente las rutas en casi todo el script.

No te muestra nada porque el `if` más interno debería, (1) comparar si la **ruta real** es un archivo, y (2) comparar si el **nombre del archivo** es `'.'` o `'..'`

Entonces la línea queda:

```php
if(is_file($directory. '/'. $archivo) && ($archivo != ".") && ($archivo != ".."))
```

La misma línea en cuestion tiene la función `if_file()`, la cual devuelve `True` si es un archivo válido o `False` para todo lo demás, incluído `'.'` y `'..'`, por lo que no es necesario hacer esas comparaciones. Entonces se puede reducir a:

```php
if(is_file($directory. '/'. $archivo))
```

---

Si bien las expresiones regulares que tienes en el penúltimo `if` supuestamente filtrarán los tipos de archivos, la verdad es que no lo hace como debería. Si un archivo tiene nombre: `fotos_jpg.pdf`, será tomado como archivo válido. Sugiero una validación por extensión.

Una mejor forma de obtener la extensión puede ser con [pathinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.pathinfo.php)

Entonces el código quedará de la siguiente forma. Observar que puse en comentario "**<-- Modificar**" donde se corrigen las concatenaciones de rutas.

```php
<?php

// ...

// Se comprueba que realmente sea la ruta de un directorio
if(is_dir($directory)){
    // Recorre todos los elementos del directorio
    while (($archivo = $dirint->read()) !== false) {
        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($archivo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if(in_array($ext, ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'tif', 'webp'])) {
            list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($directory. '/' .$archivo); // <-- Modificar
            echo '<a class="itemValueInput" data-copy="'.$folderImg. '/' .$archivo.'">'; // <-- Modificar
            echo '<img src="../../../'.$folderImg. '/' .$archivo.'" width="100%" heigth="auto" />'; // <-- Modificar
            echo '<small>Ancho: '.$width.' - Alto: '.$height.'<br />'.filesize($directory .'/' .$archivo).' bytes</small></a>'; // <-- Modificar

            echo '<div><br />var_dump: <pre>'.var_dump(getimagesize($directory. '/' .$archivo)).'</pre><br />'; // <-- Modificar
            $dataFile = pathinfo($directory. '/' .$archivo); // <-- Modificar
            echo '<br /><pre>pathinfo: '.var_dump($dataFile).'</pre><br /></div>';
        }
    }
    $dirint->close();
}
```